# Change configurable swatches order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-list, swatches, color-swatches

I want to know how can I change/set configurable swatches sort order in a products list page in Magento 2 ?

[image]

For example in the case above I want to have from top to bottom:

Colors
Shapes
Sizes

But at the moment it is:
Sizes
Shapes
Colors

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: same question here

Comment: I went over the Configurable Products addition section in the admin and tried to change the sort order of attributes from there. But no change in the product listing page. There must be a settings hidden here and there in Magento 2 which I miss.

Comment: Try it with create new configurable product.

Answer (score 4):

You have to edit configurable product, in configurable tab (product edit page) you can view option for **Edit Configurations.**

Click on **Edit Configurations,** you can see select attribute screen, go to next for step 2.

In step 2 you can see your selected attributes like **size** and **color**.

You can change position of your attributes by drag and drop from here. drag and drop from **square icon** you can see.

set you attributes position here, save your product.

Now check product on front side list page, you can see your position changes here.

Comment: do you have a solution to update all the configurable products? :D thnx in advance

Comment: You can set it by export/import product data Csv.

Comment: Can we manage sequence of attributes code value product wise? Like I have Yellow, White, Green But I want to show on product detail page as White, Green, Yellow specific product wise.